# Is any norm on $\mathbb R^n$ invariant with respect to componentwise absolute value?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, absolute-value

Given $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,...,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ , define  $ \mathbf{x}'=(|x_1|,...,|x_n|) $ .

Then, is it $||\mathbf{x}'|| = ||\mathbf{x}||$  for every norm on $ \mathbb{R}^n $  ?

NB: The answer is trivially yes for $p$-norms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may consider, for example,

$$\|(x_1,x_2)\|:=|x_1|+|x_1-x_2|.$$

Comment: Thank you. I realize that not all norms are absolute (or monotone).

Comment: I would ask a more specific question: are the norms induced by a scalar product absolute (monotone)? I always mean norms in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: @MicheleFedrizzi: It is still not true. Note that every $n\times n$ positive definite matrix defines an inner(scalar) product on $\mathbb{R}^n$. When $A$ is not diagonal, the induced norm shouldn't be absolute. For example, $A=\begin{pmatrix}2&-1\\-1&1\end{pmatrix}$ defines $\langle(x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)\rangle=2x_1y_1-x_1y_2-x_2y_1+x_2y_2$. Then $\|(x_1,x_2)\|=\sqrt{x_1^2+(x_1-x_2)^2}$ is not monotone.

Comment: Thanks again. Now, I guess that there is no relevant subset of norms with the property of monotonicity, except p-norms. Is it so?

Comment: @MicheleFedrizzi: It is still not true.